# laravel & blade templating @section error

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, lumen, templating

I want to display full name as title:

```
@section('title',  ['title' => $userdetail->fullName])
```

I have used the above code and it shows the error exception of string to object conversion.

Answer (score 1):

modify your @section to this

```
@section('title', {{$userdetail->fullName}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this --

```
@section('title', "$userdetail->fullName")
```

Wrap the second parameter inside double quotes since it renders it automatically renders a variable and normal text, whereas single quotes only render text and not variable.

**And remember that you cannot use blade echo `{{ }}` inside a blade syntax.**
like - `@section('title', {{ $userdetail->fullName }})`

Answer (score 1):

```
@section('title', $userdetail->fullName)
```

You don't need to specify it as an associative array, just put variable and section will be the value of this variable